# How to make map clickable to get another frame?

Tags: java, html, dictionary, applet, onclick

unfortunately i did not find out the right formulation of my question.

Everything i want is to create a map of an antic "city" (or camp) and make it clickable. That means after clicking on a house on that picture of map i would like to go "into" that house and see something else for example run the video or see the house from inside. I have no clue what programming language to use for this task. I would prefer Java. The thing is that it is online so it has to be working with a wordpress.

Any advice will be appreciated! Thank you so much.

Comment: if your frame size is fixed do action based on you mouse points..

Comment: http://www.360dof.com/free-java-applets/

Comment: I would prefer a better explanation/advices? Thank you anyway.

Comment: BTW it does not have to be 3D just simply map and after clicking on house some other frame with picture of house inside and some video running and some text displayed. The most important: which programming language to use so it can be compatible with a wordpress. THANK YOU :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has to be online, then Java is very poor option. Although it is possible to embed Java applets in a website, it will require users to have Java pre-installed and probably require you to sign your applet with an expensive certificate.

From the description of what you'd like to do, it seems that just HTML will do the job perfectly. Not even Javascript is required. I'd suggest the following:

1. Create a HTML-page with the image of the "map of an antic city", that was made clickable using the `HTML map tag`. [See this page for more info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp). Make sure the page is entirely filled with the image.
2. You would then need to create a separate HTML-page for each location the user may click on in the map.
3. On these pages, either include a new clickable image or a video, etc. Make sure these pages are entirely filled with their content.
4. Now include the first HTML-page we made (see point 1) using an `IFrame` in your Wordpress-website. [See this page for more info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

The result will be a clickable map embedded in your website, where any clicks by the user will result in a new clickable map or a video, etc, that will exactly fill the area of the original map.

Answer (score 1):

> The most important: which programming language to use so it can be compatible with a wordpress.

AFAIU Wordpress sites do not support Java applets.  Other languages that can embed a GUI in a web page might be ..Flash (though if WP does not support applets, I doubt they'll support serving Flash files).

Also look into [HTML/Elements/map](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/map).  It allows us to define a map that can point to various other links depending on which part of the image the mouse pointer is over.

Comment: Thank you this thing that worpress does not support applets helped me and that thing about HTML maps i have already made but i was thinking about something with some animation maybe and so on. And in a flash i have never done anything unfortunately so it might be difficult.